# scanf is not waiting for user input in a while loop

Tags: c, buffer, scanf

I have just started an Operating Systems class this summer and we are required to program in C.

I have only coded in C++ so I am brand new to C. Our first assignment is a simple prompt for input of multiple strings. We can only read in up to 10 strings.

My problem is that the `scanf()` is not waiting for the user input in the loop, the program just displays the prompt 10 times before I have a chance to enter anything. I have read that it is because `scanf()` has the newline char in the buffer so I added an extra space before `%c` in `scanf()` statement as suggested but that has not fixed the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int SIZE = 10;
    char* states[SIZE];
    int cnt = 0;

    printf ("Here\n");
    while (cnt < 10)
    {
        printf ("Enter State and Pop: ");
        scanf (" %c ", &states[cnt]);
        cnt++;
        printf ("%d\n", cnt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%c` is for reading a single character, not a string. And the argument should be a pointer to a `char`, but you're giving a pointer to a `char*`

Comment: You have an array of pointers, but you haven't allocated any memory for them to point to.

Comment: Change `char *states[SIZE];` to `char states[SIZE]`.

Comment: `scanf` even with `%s` will not accept a 2 word state like New Mexico, you would need `scanf("%[^\n]", states[cnt]);` (once memory is allocated).

Comment: @Weather Vane `scanf("%[^\n]"` is on par with `gets()`.

Comment: @chux yes of course thanks, it needs a length restriction.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* states[SIZE]; //pointers not allocated with memory
scanf (" %c ", &states[cnt]); //wrong format specifier and argument
```

- This is **undefined behaviour** as you are using the wrong format specifier and also sending in wrong argument for scanning in the string
- and more over your pointer to strings i.e, `states` is not allocated with memory

---

To avoid this, first allocate memory to each string in the `states` array

1. Include `stdlib.h` header file
2. Allocate memory and return address to each of the pointers in the `states`

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
       states[i] = malloc(max_size_of_string);
   }
   ```

Or you can allocate memory not dynamically this way :

```
char states[10][max_size_of_strings];
```

---

3. Finally use scanf this way :

   ```
   scanf (" %(size_of_string-1)[^\n]", states[cnt]);
   ```

i.e, if you have given max_size_of_string as 10 then use this way:

```
scanf (" %9[^\n]", states[cnt]);
```

This is to avoid overwriting the terminating null character

Comment: Cherubim Anand I did as you suggested and I am still getting the same result. My output is still the printf statment 10 times.

Comment: Do you know ideone.com? If yes paste your code and comment me the link so i can have a look at it...

Comment: `scanf (" %9[^\n]", states[cnt]);` change it to `scanf (" %5[^\n]", states[cnt]);` as you are only mallocing 6 for each pointer.... If you want size of string to be n the allocate`n` bytes in `malloc()` and place `n-1` in `scanf`

Comment: Change the language to C in ideone... Seems like you are doing it in Java

Comment: And you didn't end the main , add } at the end ang give in input @ stdin

Comment: What do you mean add another } ? I'm a little confused because I have a set of { } enclosing my main function

Comment: And I'm also confused as to what you mean by "at the end ang give in input @ stdin"

Comment: Still giving the same result without waiting for input
Enter State and Pop: 1
Enter State and Pop: 2
Enter State and Pop: 3
Enter State and Pop: 4
Enter State and Pop: 5
Enter State and Pop: 6
Enter State and Pop: 7
Enter State and Pop: 8
Enter State and Pop: 9
Enter State and Pop: 10

Comment: The online compilers would take in all the inputs at a time and display the whole output

Comment: I'm running it through Eclipse on my own machine and its still giving me the problem of not waiting for the input by just spitting out all of the output at once

Comment: Either you use that while to work proper or change it into a do while.

Comment: @Eric6494 maybe your program has not end running... So no changes in the code would be applied to exe... Try restarting your computer and run the program

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```
// for printf() and scanf()
#include <stdio.h>
// for malloc() and free()
#include <stdlib.h>

// Global constants should be define'd
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 100
#define STACK_SIZE 10

int main()
{
  // pointer to an array of strings (roughly)
  char *states[STACK_SIZE];
  // used as the iterator throughout
  int i;
  // allocate memory for every string in the array "states"
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Normally sizeof(char) == 1, but that's how it works in general:
    // the number of elements times the size of on element, be it
    // a char (1) an integer (2,4 or 8 these times) or some
    // complicated struct
    states[i] = malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    // check if it actually happened
    if (states[i] == NULL) {
      // the error message should explain a bit more than just:
      fputs("malloc() failed\n", stderr);
      // free the already allocated memory
      while (i >= 0) {
        free(states[i--]);
      }
      // exit with a return code signaling an error
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
  // reset iterator
  i = 0;
  // I would have used a for-loop, but it's a matter of taste, I guess
  while (i < 10) {
    printf("Enter State and Pop: ");
    // scan 99 characters of the input between start of line and line-end
    // one less than MAX_STRING_SIZE to leave room for the string-end '\0'

    // scanf() returns the number of characters read or EOF in case of an error
    // You might find it useful at one time.
    scanf(" %99[^\n]", states[i]);
    // Print what we just gathered
    printf("State %d is %s\n", i, states[i]);
    // increment iterator, if that is not obvious--but sometimes it isn't
    i++;
  }
  // Just a string to stdout, so puts(). The function printf() is too expensive for that
  puts("All states:");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("State %d is %s\n", i, states[i]);
    // normally not necessary, the OS does it here at the end main but
    // it should always be the habit of a good programmer to clean up at the end
    free(states[i]);
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Why (MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char))? Why =>> MAX_STRING_SIZE * 1?

Comment: I appreciate your advice and detailed comments but unfortunately scanf still is not waiting for input and all of the output is being released prematurely. The output I get when I run your code is Enter State and Pop: State 0 is 
Enter State and Pop: State 1 is 
Enter State and Pop: State 2 is 
Enter State and Pop: State 3 is 
Enter State and Pop: State 4 is 
Enter State and Pop: State 5 is

Comment: @Michi as described in the comment: I wanted to point out the general way to do it and that `sizeof(char) == 1` is an exception from the rule. I apologize that was unclear.

Comment: @Eric6494 Than you are doing something fundamentally wrong. How did you compile it?

Answer (score 0):

the first getchar() gets your input string and the second getchar gets the Enter key u press ;) and that's it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    char* states[SIZE];
    int cnt = 0;

    printf("Here\n");
    while (cnt < 10)
    {

        printf("Enter State and Pop: ");
        states[cnt] = (char*)getchar();
        getchar();
        cnt++;
        printf("%d\n", cnt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```